# Simple alternative for gstreamer on android

Tags: android, gstreamer

For training and fun I want to build an android app, that is able to **stream audio from one device to another**. It will be a simple baby-phone app.
I've tried using gstreamer, but have some trouble including the binaries and building the eclipse project. However, now I am looking for alternatives. Does any one know a simple one? Or is there even some android api stuff I can use? Please note: the difficult thing is not receive a stream, but provide one...
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are both phones in the same network (if not, you might need a server)?
Which audio Codec do you want to use (mp3/ogg? mp3 encoding might require a license, ogg's for free; however there should be java libs for both)

Comment: Yes, both in the same network. The receiver (who is consuming the stream) knows ip address and port of the sender (serving the stream). I don't prefer some codec, just what works best to do **live streaming from build in mic** (I did not mention this explicit before)